# Python print issue with different block process

Tags: python, file, block, indentation

I have an issue with my script and need your help.
I may not used the correct wording to explain but I hope it will be clear enough.

I have 3 files , file1.txt file2.txt and file3.txt when line 1 in each file correspond to same object.

```
$ cat file1.txt 
server1, windows, 1, 120, running
server2, linux, 1, 250, offline
server3, centos, 0, 60, maintenance
server4, windows, 1, 123, running
server5, linux, 0, 145, offline
server6, windows, 1, 123, running
server7, linux, 0, 145, offline
server8, windows, 1, 123, running
server9, windows, 1, 123, running

$ cat file2.txt 
1, 1, 1, 1, 34, 1, 1, 1, 97, 1, 1, 1, 1
101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 23, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0
1, 21, 1, 1, 34, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
101, 73, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 1, 14, 101, 101
13, 101, 101, 101, 101, 0, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101
101, 101, 101, 6, 101, 101, 22, 101, 101, 101, 11, 101, 101

$ cat file3.txt 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101
101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101
```

I have the following script:

```
chance = ''
myliststatus = ''

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    file2 = f2.read().splitlines()
with open('file3.txt', 'r') as f3:
    file3 = f3.read().splitlines()

varfiles2 = [[int(x) for x in y.split(', ')] for y in file2]
varfiles3 = [[int(x) for x in y.split(', ')] for y in file3]

for varfile2, varfile3 in zip(varfiles2, varfiles3):
    for fi2,fi3 in zip(varfile2, varfile3):
        if ( 0 < fi2 < 100 and fi3 == 0):
            chance = "Low"
        elif (fi2 == 0 and 0 < fi3 < 100):
            chance = "high"
        elif ( fi2 == 0 and fi3 == 0):
            chance = "medium"
        else:
            chance = "null"
    print chance

with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        mylist = line.split(", ")
        if mylist[2] == "0":
            myliststatus = "staging"
        elif mylist[2] == "1":
            myliststatus = "Production"
        else:
            myliststatus = "decommissioned"

        print myliststatus
```

what I need is to be able to print the result of chance and myliststatus in the same line so result of chance and myliststatus for line 1 are printed in the same line and the output should be 9 lines with 2 columns like below:

```
print chance, myliststatus

null, Production
null, Production
null, staging
medium, Production
null, staging
null, Production
null, staging
null, Production
null, decommissioned
```

but because the indentation is different form my 2 blocks the result is not the same if I change the indentation of one of the blocks.

what is the best way to do this for these 2 blocks and if I need to add additional blocks as well?

many thanks

**UPDATE**

```
chance = 'tbd'

s1 = ["S", "stime", "M", "mtime","T", "ttime","W", "wtime","Th", "thtime", "F", "ftime", "Sa"]
static = "S"

with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    p1 = f1.read().splitlines()
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    bgfile2 = f2.read().splitlines()
with open('file3.txt', 'r') as f3:
    bgfile3 = f3.read().splitlines()


varbgfiles2 = [[int(x) for x in y.split(', ')] for y in bgfile2]
varbgfiles3 = [[int(x) for x in y.split(', ')] for y in bgfile3]


for varp1, varbgfile2, varbgfile3 in zip(p1, varbgfiles2, varbgfiles3):
    for p1,f,i,s in zip(p1, varbgfile2, varbgfile3, s1):
        if ( f > 0 and i == 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 1):
            chance = "OK1"
        elif ( f == 0 and i > 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 1):
            chance = "NOK1"
        elif ( f > 0 and i > 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 1):
            chance = "NULL1"
        elif ( f == 0 and i == 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 1):
            chance = "BAD1"
        elif ( f > 0 and i == 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 0):
            chance = "OK0"
        elif ( f == 0 and i > 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 0):
            chance = "NOK0"
        elif ( f > 0 and i > 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 0):
            chance = "NULL0"
        elif ( f == 0 and i == 0 and static == s and p1[2] == 0):
            chance = "BAD0"
        print chance
```

so I should expect the following for (line1,2,3 in file1) & (line1,2,3/column1 in file2 and file3) as the static is set to S first column in the list s1.

```
 line 1 chance = NULL1
 line 2 chance = NULL1
 line 3 chance = NULL0
```

I hope this will clarify the question, many thanks.

Comment: Any simple way to achieve this. I am stuck and cannot find how to solve it. thanks for your help

Comment: There are 8 lines in file1.txt, and 9 lines in file2.txt and in file3.txt; how would that match anyway?

Comment: I edited the post - thanks for pointing the error. do you know I can do this?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't loop over the contents of file1, file2 and file3 at the same time. You already loop over the contents of file2 and file3 together, just add the file1 contents to it.

Comment: yes this is good point. I am trying to do this but got issue with the code - thanks for your help

Comment: Simple debugging by `print`ing `fi2` and `fi3` would show that after mapping, `fi2` and `fi3` are (still) lists. You can't compare the lists to integers in your if-statements, you need to use a (the first?) element.

Comment: I added a new updated code for what I need to achieve but so far not able to make it work. I need to match s1 list day to the column of the file2 and file3 to process the loop and check the conditions to output the correct value for a specific day. so if the day is S then first column in file1 and file2 must be read, if this is M then it should be 3rd column as the M is 3rd element in s1 - thanks for your help - I am stuck on this

Comment: Did you do the debugging I suggested? Print the values inside the double for loop, check that they are what you expect them to be. For example, you are reusing the variable name `p1` for different variables, in the for loops: that's going to be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to combine the information from the 3 files. You are using zip to combine information from 2 files, but [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) can take any number of iterables - it will return an iterator of 3-tuples if you pass it 3 sequences.

```
import csv
f1 = csv.reader(open('file1.txt'))
f2 = csv.reader(open('file2.txt'))
f3 = csv.reader(open('file3.txt'))

for part1, part2, part3 in zip(f1, f3, f3):
    part2 = map(int, part2)
    part3 = map(int, part3)
    # process part1, 2 and 3 at the same time.
```

Comment: I tried but wasn't able to make it work - I posted the new code in the questions. thanks for your hlep

Comment: I am not able to make this script working with the 3 elements. anyone can help me how to do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you explain it in words? What do the values in the 3 files represent? The rows in file1 look like descriptions of machines. Each sequence of numbers in files 2 and 3 correspond to that machine. You want to combine those numbers together into something that represents "chance", right? How would you do that for one machine where f2 = [1, 1, 1, 97, 1, ...] and f3 = [101, 101, 101, ...]?

Comment: Hi babbageclunk, you pointed a good point. I have another mapping from the file 2 and 3 that is base on a static list so for example if the static is column 1 then the loop should look at line 1 in file1.txt and in line1/column1 in file2.txt and file3.txt. please let me know if this is not clear I will edit the questions and add the static list. thanks a lot

Comment: anyone knows how to fix this?